# Data Storing from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to store data to Database from JSP page but not want to send the values to another JSP page or servlet . I want to store the data from same JSP page where it is accepting ?

Comment: _but not want to send the values to another JSP page or servlet_ can we know reason for this? there is way to do this, but that is a very very bad practice.

Comment: You can call a function that stores data from your JSP. Regardless, you have a very ill-formed questions

Comment: Welcome to SO! btw please learn on how to post questions here, so that you will get better responses!

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question ?

Comment: Is submitting to the *same* JSP an option? In trying to determine if your problem is conceptual, or just odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code you want to execute (the code that would write some data to a database) inside a function block within the jsp page, something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="param2save">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<%
  String parameterTosave = request.getParameter("param2save");
  // run the saveStuff
   if (parameterTosave!=null) {
         saveStuffToDB(parameterToSave);
   }
%>
<%!

  private void saveStuffToDB(String Saveme){
    // get a connection, 
    // insert data in to database.  - use PreparedStatement, since that is more safe. 
    // close connection

  }
%>
```

On the other hand, many people think this is a bad practice since the JSP-layer was tought to be the View part of the Model View Controller setup. There for it should only display data, not do any work on it, such as this. But, sometimes this can be the easiest way to patch a legacy system or to do similar work.